# .Selected Causes a compile error

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing code to copy and paste all checked boxes in a multiselect listbox. Below is an example of the code I am using.

```
strValue1 = ""
For i = 1 To Area.ListCount
If Me.Area.Selected(i - 1) Then
    strValue1 = strValue1 + Area.List(i - 1) + ", "
End If
Next i
If strValue1 <> "" Then
strValue1 = Left(strValue1, Len(strValue1) - 2)
strFinal = strFinal +  strValue1 + vbCrLf
End If
```

When I try to run it, a compile error (method or data member not found) comes up and. Selected is highlighted.

Comment: Are you sure `Area` is a valid method on whatever `Me` is?

Comment: Yes, what is Area? A Listbox perhaps? Do you have Option Explicit at the top of your code? That can help resolve bizarre compile errors.

Comment: From `Area.ListCount` it seems `Area` is a list, because the variable is initalized, so the `Selected` method shouldn't be a problem. However, you don't use `Me` to get this value; when you use it, instead, you get a compile error. This seems to be due to the fact that `Area` exists as a variable but is not a property (child) of `Me`. Just remove `Me` and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, much appreciated. Area is a listbox. I tried removing area and adding option explicit at the top of my code, but neither seemed to work. I keep getting the same error.